# С++ std::map заполнение из файла

Tags: c++, map

Есть вот такой вот map

```
static std::map<std::string, uint32_t> g_targets = {
{ "Shaggy Dog", 17939 },
{ "Chubby Dog", 17966 },
{ "Panda", 18098 },
{ "Snowball", 18426 },
{ "Crow", 18439 },
{ "Horse", 21012 },
{ "Horn Bow +0", 13138 },    
};
```

Как мне содержимое g_targets заполнить из файла?
На просторах интернет нашел вот такой вот код

```
std::ifstream myFile("D:\\Myfile.txt");
    std::string key;
    uint32_t value;
    if (!myFile.is_open()) std:: cout << "Error opening file\n"; // если не открылся
    else if (myFile.peek() == EOF) std:: cout << "This file is empty\n"; // если первый символ конец файла
    else std:: cout << "\nAll OK! File is open!\n\n";
    static std::map<std::string, uint32_t> g_targets;
        while (myFile >> key >> value)          
            g_targets[key] = value;         
        for (auto& p : g_targets)
        {
            std::cout << p.first << p.second << "\n";
        }


    for (auto const& target : g_targets){...}
```

Пока что моя попытка подстроить под себя ничем не увенчалась. Показывает в цикле, что файл открыт нормально и на этом все. Я понимаю, что это топорная работа и где то, что то не досмотрел. Но на данный момент не понял, где и что.
Так же сомневаюсь, что правильно сделал цикл for, для вывода в консоль прочтенного из файла.

Comment: Читать по одной записи, и добавлять. В чем ваша проблема конкретнее?

Comment: Проблема в уровне знания С++. У меня он чуть выше плинтуса =)

Answer (score 0):

Для чтения файла есть [std::basic_ifstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream). Для добавления записи в `std::map<>` есть [множество методов](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). В цикле добавляете все нужные записи, в чём проблема?

`upd:`

```
std::ifstream infile("название_файла");
std::string key;
uint32_t value;
std::map<std::string, uint32_t> myMap;
while (infile >> key >> value)
    myMap[key] = value;
```

Comment: Не лень читать. Просто я не особо программист. Вот понадобилось подредактировать немного готовую библиотеку, для удобства пользования.
Спасибо за подсказку. Если не сложно, можно прокомментировать каждую строку?

Comment: @Alehander я привёл пример, как заполнять `std::map<>`. В нём `infile` - ваш файловый поток из первой ссылки, `key` и `value` - строка и `uint32_t` переменные, вроде всё должно быть понятно. Если вы совсем не знаете `c++`, то почитайте туториал какой-нибудь для начинающих, смысл копировать, не понимая?

Comment: Это как чистка форсунок в глубинке. Сам не умеешь, а сделать некому, а без чистки не поехать. Так и тут, библиотека рабочая, только не удобно сделан момент со списком, этот список внутри кода и каждый раз компилировать код из-за надобности внести в список изменений, не очень перспектива. Вот и приходится влезать в дебри.
Я бы и был рад не сам редактировать, а что бы знающий человек это сделал, но у меня таких знакомых нет. =(

Comment: @Alehander обновил, теперь понятно?

Comment: Спасибо, так более понятно. Сейчас буду разбираться, как использовать с умом =)

Comment: Теперь столкнулся с другой проблемой
Теперь Е0020 "Идентификатор g_targets не определен"
g_targets это у вас в примере myMap